# Javascript : filter two array of object by id and return specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm trying to filter these two arrays of objects by their id (`id` & `userId`).

I want to return only the title where `id` and `userId` are equals

Thank you !

```js
const usersData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  }
]

const albumsData = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "FooBar"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Trolololo"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
  }
]

const results = usersData.map(({ id }) =>
    albumsData.filter(({ userId }) => id === userId)
  );

console.log(results);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: id in also userData. 
I did not mentioned id albumsData

Comment: Are you answering the question I deleted?

Comment: The question just says "where id and userId are equals" it doesn't say which `id` it's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, but will return a nested array, so just use `flatMap` instead of `map`. And if you just want the title, just chain another `.map` to it:

```js
const usersData = [{"id": 1,"name": "Leanne Graham","username": "Bret","email": "Sincere@april.biz",}];
const albumsData = [{"userId": 1,"id": 1,"title": "FooBar"},{"userId": 1,"id": 2,"title": "Trolololo"},{"userId": 3,"id": 3,"title": "omnis laborum odio"},{"userId": 4,"id": 4,"title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"}];

const results = usersData.flatMap(({ id }) =>
    albumsData.filter(({ userId }) => id === userId)
).map(({title}) => title);

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = albumData.filter((data) => data.userId === usersData[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you'll get a nested array using `map`. But that might actually be desired if you add another item to the `usersData` array as you'll get the results grouped by index. If not, use `flatMap` with another `map` on the end to get the title.

```js
const results = usersData.flatMap(({ id }) =>
    albumsData.filter(({ userId }) => id === userId)
  ).map(entry=>entry.title)
```

Yields:

```
["FooBar","Trolololo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want the title values?  In that case you code is find but just get the titles from that i.e.: Probably not the super most efficient but the verbose part at the end will show you what is going on there perhaps.

```js
const usersData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
}];

const albumsData = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "FooBar"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Trolololo"
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "omnis laborum odio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
  }
];

const results = usersData.map(({
    id
  }) =>
  albumsData.filter(({
    userId
  }) => id === userId)
);
console.log(results);
// an array of titles
var titles = results[0].map((el) => {return el.title;});
console.log(titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I can see two use cases.

1. If you have a single object inside `usersData` array, Then you can simply achieve it by using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

   Demo **:**

   ```js
   const usersData = [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Leanne Graham",
       "username": "Bret",
       "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
     }
   ]

   const albumsData = [
     {
       "userId": 1,
       "id": 1,
       "title": "FooBar"
     },
     {
       "userId": 1,
       "id": 2,
       "title": "Trolololo"
     },
     {
       "userId": 3,
       "id": 3,
       "title": "omnis laborum odio"
     },
     {
       "userId": 4,
       "id": 4,
       "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
     }
   ];

   const res = albumsData.find(obj => (usersData[0].id === obj.id) && (usersData[0].id === obj.userId));

   console.log(res.title);
   ```
2. If `usersData` contains multiple users object then you can achieve that by combination of [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

   Demo **:**

   ```js
   const usersData = [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Leanne Graham",
       "username": "Bret",
       "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
     }
   ]

   const albumsData = [
     {
       "userId": 1,
       "id": 1,
       "title": "FooBar"
     },
     {
       "userId": 1,
       "id": 2,
       "title": "Trolololo"
     },
     {
       "userId": 3,
       "id": 3,
       "title": "omnis laborum odio"
     },
     {
       "userId": 4,
       "id": 4,
       "title": "non esse culpa molestiae omnis sed optio"
     }
   ];

   const res = usersData.map(userObj =>
     albumsData.find(obj => (userObj.id === obj.userId) && (userObj.id === obj.id))
   );

   console.log(res);
   ```